# Dynamically defined setter method is not called from block

Tags: ruby, lambda, metaprogramming, dsl

I've been writing a DSL, and I'm trying to get a dynamically defined method to be accessible from a lambda. This works fine unless you try to do a setter `something=` in which case the lambda invocation just sets a local variable instead.

A simplified example:

```
class Caller
  attr_accessor :cmd
  def callme
    self.class.send(:define_method, "something") { puts "Retrieve Something" }
    self.class.send(:define_method, "something=") {|val| puts "Set Something = #{val}" }
    instance_exec &cmd
  end
end

c = Caller.new
c.cmd = lambda { something = 1 }
c.callme
```

This also works fine if I use `self.something=`. However that's less than ideal in the case of a DSL.

Is it possible to get this to work without `self.` in front of the method?

Answer (score 2):

This has absolutely nothing to do with blocks or dynamically defined methods. It's just simple basic Ruby syntax:

```
foo = bar
```

is local variable assignment. Always.

```
self.foo = bar
```

is a method call.

> Is it possible to get this to work without `self.` in front of the method?

No.

This is just basic Ruby syntax. The `define_method` metaprogramming, the `instance_exec`, the blocks in your code sample are just a red herring, the problem can be demonstrated with a *much* simpler example:

```
def foo=(*)
  puts 'I was called!'
end

foo=('bar') # even removing spaces and adding parentheses won't help!

self.foo = 'bar'
# I was called!
```

Note also that `foo=` is `private` but was actually called with an explicit receiver (which is illegal for `private` methods). That's a special exception for setter methods in the rule for `private` methods, because they otherwise couldn't be called at all, precisely because they would *always* be interpreted as a local variable assignment.